# express routing triggers: "Can't set headers after they are sent." error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, express, ejs

I am new to Express, and having trouble sending data from backend to front end. Here is what I want to do: I have a Google Map API on the homepage (`home.ejs`). `app.js` is the server code: when the homepage is loaded, `app.js` generate some random locations and send to `home.ejs`, so `home.ejs` use those locations as Markers. Now I want to add an event listener to each of these Markers, so that when the mouse is over the Marker, it sends a GET request to server, to request a picture to display.

I feel it a big challenge for me to send the request/data back and forth. When the mouse is over, the `home.ejs` sends a GET Request to `/getImage/:num` route, and `app.get("/getImage/:num", function(req, res){})` responds to that request by retrieving the image url, and redirect to `"/"` and sends the url to it. This is where I get the "`Can't set headers after they are sent"`.

I am so new to Express and ejs that I don't even know if I am on the right track. How should I implement this to get the communication through?

This is the `app.js` server file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

var lng_min = -84.161;
var lng_max = -83.688; 
var lat_min = 35.849;
var lat_max = 36.067;

var urls = [
    "http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2015/01/file_21032_the-most-popular-dog-and-cat-names.jpg",
    "http://qltyctrl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Sad-Dog-and-Cat.jpg",
    "https://blog-photos.dogvacay.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/dog-cat-smarter-ftr.jpg",
    "http://qltyctrl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Dog-and-Cat-on-a-Log.jpg",
    "http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/31730/cat-and-dog_1-jpg.jpg",
    "http://www.vetlocator.com/dailypaws/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/dog-cat2.jpg",
    "http://qltyctrl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Old-Dog-and-Cat-Sleepy-Embrace.jpg",
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXNMdvNfc3WYMqbPrJrnjgHJRp2zB1y9vx545LfO-_U5_yvgBo",
    "http://www.vetlocator.com/dailypaws/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/dog-cat8.jpg",
    "http://www.maddiesfund.org/assets/metaImage/robust-dog-cat-foster.jpg"
]

var numLocations = 10;
var data = []; 

function generateData() {
    // generate random locations and the url to download pictures
    for (var i = 0; i < numLocations; ++i) {
        var lng = Math.random() * (lng_max - lng_min) + lng_min;
        var lat = Math.random() * (lat_max - lat_min) + lat_min;
        var tuple = {
            id: i,
            lng: lng,
            lat: lat,
            pic: urls[i]
        };
        data.push(tuple);
    }
}

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    //res.send("Hello it works");
    data = [];
    generateData();
    res.render("home.ejs", {data: data});
});

app.get("/getImg/:num", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.num);
  var i = Number(req.params.num);
  res.redirect("/");
  res.send({imgUrl: data[i].pic});
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
   console.log("Server Started!"); 
});
```

`home.ejs` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/app.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>

    <script>
      var data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
      console.log(data.length);
      function initMap() {
        var loc = {lat: 35.9606, lng: -83.9207};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: loc
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { 
            var loc = {lat: data[i].lat, lng: data[i].lng}; 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: loc,
                  map: map
                  // id: i
            }); 

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker) {
            return function() {
                  // var content = '<div id="imgDisplay">'
                  //                   + '<img src="http://www.maddiesfund.org/assets/metaImage/robust-dog-cat-foster.jpg">'  
                  //                 + '</div>';
                  // infowindow.setContent(content);
                  // infowindow.open(map, marker);


              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              var params = 3;
              xhr.open('GET','/getImg/'+params, true);
                  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                      console.log(responseText);
                }
                  }
            //xhr.send(params);
            xhr.send();


            }
         })(marker));


         }
      }
    </script>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOwfkV_GbUXyH2s8iD0gS6pje9J3R96dM&callback=initMap">
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "app.js responds to that request by retrieving the image url, and redirect to `"/"` and sends the url to it." After reading this, I don't understand exactly what you want to happen. You can either redirect to another path using `redirect` which sends a `3xx` HTTP response (at which point the handler for that path will run) *or* you can send data with `send` which sends a `2xx` response. These are mutually exclusive -- either the response is a redirect response or a data response. Do you want the top-level page to redirect to `/` after a request to `/getImg`?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The Google Map is on the homepage ("/"). When I send the GET request, it is sent to "/getImg/:num". app.get("/getImg/:num",) responds to that GET request and fetches the image URL from the data matrix, but I want it to redirect to "/" so I can display the image on the homepage ("/")

Comment: Okay, I think the answer here is: your understanding of what `redirect("/")` does is wrong. `redirect("/")` sends a `3xx` (probably `301` or `302`) HTTP response and says, "I don't have an answer for you; instead, try loading data from the path `/`." But you don't want to do that -- you already have the data and are ready to send it! Instead, I think want you mean to do is send the URL from the `urls` array, and then on the client side, do `img = new Image(); img.src=responseText; document.body.appendChild(img)`. Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly right!!! I already the data and want just to send it. But without "redirecting" (which I misunderstood), will the data be sent to "/" or "/getImg/:num"? Thank you so much for helping me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the purpose of `redirect`. Express's `redirect` function says, "This path does not have an answer; instead try sending a request to this other path and see what it says." (This is done by a `3xx` response like `301` or `302`.)

Your confusion is that you think you need to tell the client which page should render the given URL. But that is not necessary: the server doesn't tell the client *how* to render the data it sends. The server just sends data, and the client decides what to do with it.

The good news is that your client-side JavaScript is doing its job correctly. It's using an `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch data from the server. Simply have the server actually send that data with the `send` function and *don't* call `redirect`. Once your client-side has the URL to load, you can load it in an `<img>` element with

```
var img = new Image();
img.src=responseText;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

inside your `onreadystatechange` listener. You can use `document.getElementById(...)`
 to get a different element if you don't want to add the element to your `body`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and explaining the concept to me!!! I just got it work.